# Sort csv file by three columns using command?

Tags: windows, sorting, csv, batch-file, command-line

I read many of article in stackoverflow, but I still cannot do the sorting.

The case is like this : 
I have a csv file with 9 columns without header like below :

```
D,0000001,2016/01/01 01:00,111,0.000,0000008,10.000,NET,Computer
B,0000002,2016/01/01 01:30,111,0.000,0000001,10.000,NET,Computer
C,0000003,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000001,10.000,ORG,Computer
E,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000003,10.000,ORG,Computer
E,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000003,10.000,COM,Computer
C,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000002,10.000,COM,Computer
```

The output I want is order by 2 (000001) , 6 (0000008),8 (NET) columns and output to new csv file like below:

```
C,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000002,10.000,COM,Computer
E,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000003,10.000,COM,Computer
E,0000001,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000003,10.000,ORG,Computer
D,0000001,2016/01/01 01:00,111,0.000,0000008,10.000,NET,Computer
B,0000002,2016/01/01 01:30,111,0.000,0000001,10.000,NET,Computer
C,0000003,2016/01/01 02:00,121,0.000,0000001,10.000,ORG,Computer
```

I have tried some code like this but not work :

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (input.csv) do set a[%%b,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i] =%%
for /F "tokens=2-10 delims=[,]=" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%b,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
```

Does anyone can help me? I am new in typing command script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach was quite good. Just the order of field values was not correct set to get the wanted sort order for output.

```
@echo off
if not exist input.csv goto :EOF
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (input.csv) do set "a[%%b,%%f,%%h,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%g,%%i]=%%"
del input.csv
for /F "tokens=2-10 delims=[,]=" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%d,%%a,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%b,%%h,%%c,%%i>>input.csv
endlocal
```

The environment variables are created here with `%%b,%%f,%%h,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%g,%%i` instead of `%%b,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i` which of course requires also `%%d,%%a,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%b,%%h,%%c,%%i` instead of `%%b,%%a,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i` on output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried to do myself. It is as same as yours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (input.csv) do set "a[%%b%%f%%h]=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%a
```

However, the result you show is *not* ordered as you described in the question. If you want an *inverse order* by `%%f` field, you may use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (input.csv) do (
   set /A "invF=100000000-1%%f"
   set "a[%%b!invF!%%h]=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i"
)
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%a
```